# Firefox themes usable in Seamonkey?

Tags: firefox, themes, seamonkey

I find it very odd that for SeaMonkey there are so very few themes available.

(Half of which are not working with the latest version, and the rest look like they were made in the former century.)

Is it possible to make some not too complicated changes in a Firefox theme so as to have it usable in Seamonkey, or is there a more complicated logic involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A big improvement was made by some adaptative themes which take system look and icons:

[GNOMErunner/GTK Revived (Freedesktop)](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/seamonkey/addon/gnomerunnerfd-revived/?src=cb-dl-users)

Also, [GNOMErunner](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/seamonkey/addon/gnomerunnergtk-revived/?src=search). For this there is also [GNOMErunner Options](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/seamonkey/addon/gnomerunner-options/?src=search).

The first integrates the system by default. If you use the GNOMErunner Options addon, be sure to set 'Freedesktop' under icons tab to get the system icons in the browser.

This theme in KDE:

[image]

In elementaryOS:

[image]

Also,the simple Firefox-like themes (that come on top of the default complete one) are now also available [for Seamonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/seamonkey/themes/):

[image]

[image]